# Deleting an OpenStack instance from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, openstack

I have written a PowerShell script which will get the InstanceID from a txt file. They are in this format `c5d1fa69-fe2d-4a5b-8446-5c9751429e48`.

I was trying to delete the instance using this ID, but that doesn't work correctly.

If I change `$ID` for `"c5d1fa69-fe2d-4a5b-8446-5c9751429e48"` it works correctly.

```
$instancesID = Get-Content C:\instance.txt

foreach ($entry in $instancesID) {
    #Get rid of the white space from txt file
    $ID = $entry.Trim()
}
nova delete $ID
```

How I can fetch the ID from text file, so that it executes the command like this:

```
nova delete c5d1fa69-fe2d-4a5b-8446-5c9751429e48
```

Comment: based on your code, reverse your last two lines so the delete is inside your curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Kory Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943014/deleting-an-openstack-instance-from-powershell#comment72982795_42943014) pointed out, you most likely just need to put the `nova` commandline inside the loop:

```
foreach ($entry in $instancesID) {
    $ID = $entry.Trim()
    nova delete $ID
}
```